# eclipse failing to print the output because of some error

Tags: java, eclipse

Even when I did everything said in the java tutorial, I got this error.
This is my code:

```
class code{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("coding...");
    }
}
```

the output is this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>
> at code.code.main(code.java:2)

Comment: If you're using eclipse there should be a marker in the file (a red underline and/or a red circle with an X in it) indicating where and what the compilation error is. What's it telling you?

Comment: Looks like you are missing package declaration (what is in line number 2)?

Comment: Provide full source code.

Comment: it is saying that the declared package does not met the expected package. i dont know why i did follow that guy in tutorial in every point.

Comment: Ok, *that* is the information that we really needed to know. You're not using the default package, so in order to compile your class you need to put a `package` statement as the *first line in the file* telling the compiler what package the class belongs to. In your case, it looks like it should be `package code;`

Comment: somewhere in the app it is saying package explorer. is it the one u are looking for ?

Comment: @JonK it worked thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a package at beginning of the file, like this:

```
package code;
```

And your full source code should be with a public class, like this:
Try to make your class public and try again

```
public  class code{
    public static void main(String args[])
   {
      System.out.println("coding...");
   }
}
```

Comment: If you feel it worked, then please mark it correct by clicking the grey checkmark icon and it will turn green to be marked correct. This is so people who see this question in the future can see which answer was correct. @Computerengineer

Answer (score 1):

Try to make your class public and try again

```
public  class code{
    public static void main(String args[])
   {
      System.out.println("coding...");
   }
}
```

Comment: Compilation error is due to a missing package statement, this won't fix it

Answer (score 0):

As the problem is with the package declaration:

When you did everything as the guy in the tutorial said, I think it should work. Assuming you are not using an IDE: Your `.java` File should be in at least one folder below the `src` folder. The whole path after the `src` folder represents the package. 
So if the location of your file is for example `MyJavaProject\src\exercise\code\myFile.java`

the first line in `myFile.java` should be `package exercise.code;`